# One div below, not to right, of other

Tags: css, css-float

RE this on eBay: http://www.ebay.com/itm/281670060888

On my own site (at http://sallymilo.com/template-din.html) and when running on my own computer, the right side div aligns to the top of the left side div, but when I put it on eBay, the right side div is below the left - even if I make the tabbed section 200 pixels narrower.

A bit of the main CSS:

```css
.row1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: url(https://myimagefiles.com/dinnerman/tbg.png);
}

.row1l {
  width: 26%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
  float: left;
}

.row1r {
  width: 64%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  float: left;
}
```

And a bit of the tabbed section CSS:

```
.tabholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 14em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* base font size for em-scaling */

.tabholder div.tabtops {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Why you are using float with position ?? With position relative you can make it wherever you want...just by using top left and right

Comment: i would suggest to remove the margin-right of .row1r and or decrease width down to 63%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in ebay the width of the container is lower than `1000px`.
The because of the fact that your inner sections with hardcoded widths they break.

I suggest you to use width with `%`, in that way not matter what will be the with of the container the inner sections will take the number of the percentage that you gave.

```css
.container {
margin: 20px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
overflow: hidden;
}

.col-1 {
width: 20%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
float: left;
}

.col-2{
width: 80%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-1">col-1</div>
<div class="col-2">col-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Narrowing the template from 1000 to 950 px was the main thing needed, though I adjusted the width of the 2 problem divs.